# How can I list all the pages of a Drupal site in csv format?

Tags: 7

My goal is to get a .csv file list of the titles/urls for all "pages" in a Drupal site, including all Views, panel pages, and nodes, etc.

### Potential incomplete solutions:

1. Using the [xmlsitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module to generates xml then convert it to .csv format. This gets content types and menu links, but not views pages or panel pages or other cases. The downside here is that it only outputs the urls. It'd be nice to also have the titles.
2. Querying menu_links or menu_router tables. These list all the drupal paths, but not node paths or anything that requires the variable substitutions, ie "node/%".

I'm curious if there is a more straight forward way to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494411/how-to-get-all-paths-in-drupal-install 
Though it doesn't provide a clear example solution.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a dirty script to query the node, menu_router, and menu_links tables: https://gist.github.com/dooug/b102a683d4e4854defba

This could be improved upon. The upside is that it includes "path,title" of all nodes, panel pages, view pages, etc. The downside is it includes all admin pages. Also, it includes lots of duplicates between the menu_links and menu_router tables. Please fork with your suggestions.